# jQuery issue on IE8 + mouseenter event

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'd like to remove the class of a div when I hover the li of my nav.

Here's my piece of code:

```
$('li').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('.slide .active').removeClass('active');
});
```

It works perfectly except on IE8.

The line $('.slide .active').removeClass('active'); works, but if I put the line in  $('li').on('mouseenter', function(){});, it doesn't work...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: which jQuery version are you using? Jquery 2.x has dropped support for IE8. Have you checked your console for error?

Comment: I use the 1.9.1 version. And I have no error on the console...

Comment: you should then provide relevant HTML code in question and a jsfiddle which replicates your issue.

Comment: yes thanks it helped! http://jsbin.com/ATojUrOS/1/edit

Comment: when I use  $('.home-nav li') if .home-nav is a nav, it doesn't work on IE8, but if .home-nav is a div, it works! I don't know why...

Comment: I tested it on IE8 mode (IE10) and jsbin works. IE8 is not supposed to support natively NAV tag, so you should include like in jsbin the html5 shiv `<!--[if lt IE 9]> <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js
"></script> <![endif]-->` NAV tag should be diplayed as block, maybe it is your issue, i don't know